# Does using state management such as Redux or Vuex make the web application faster?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, redux, vuex, state-management

Does storing data to central store makes the web application faster?

One of the reasons that I think is that once the data is fetched from an API, you have data to "pre-show" to the user next time when the user comes back to that view.

Meanwhile, if we were to not use state management, users have to wait every single time until the data is fetched.

Are these statements correct?

Comment: Thats true but it does not happen automatically, you still need to apply logic and/or add a caching library to your actions or to your APIs so that they calls are not made every time the page opens. This depends on how you implement things.

Comment: @hvaughan3 is _caching_ a proper word in this case? Simple checking for data existence in store is enough

Comment: The main purpose of Vuex/Redux is help the developers better handle the state outside of the components. The reason you stated is one natural (or subsidiary) benefit after implements global state management.

Comment: @kinduser Yea just meant to say that Vuex can make caching and other state management integrations easier to implement depending on what your app needs but it does not do all of those things out of the box for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these statements are correct.